# What is needed to access hidden attributes in quiet mode

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

EDIT 2: My question boils down to: what do I need to add to my API requests in order to retrieve the data that is being hidden when a track's stats are being hidden by quiet mode? Do I need to add a secret token from the owner of the tracks?

EDIT: After giving this another shot this morning, the examples given on the developer page do give playback_count, but when I try it on other playlists, the tracks are not returning that attribute. Is playback_count specific to particular playlists?

On quite a few of the examples, playback_count for tracks is being mentioned as an expected returned attribute, but I am not getting it while using the JavaScript API. Has this been deprecated?